# Html file sent from list

Tags: php, marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

From below link.

[Dynamic html mail process](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23339/dynamic-html-mail-process)

My individual file size is below 25 Kb,overall the folder size is above 115 Mb.All html newsletter inside it.

what is the size of LIBXML_PARSEHUGE?

Already implmented below link in our process of mailing newsletter.

Process: [Dynamic html mail process through single list](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22796/dynamic-html-mail-process-through-single-list)

Please let me know if any other solution to sent the html newsletter in all subscriber from one list.All html newsletter different from another.

Below is my code snippet.

```
$newListID='******'; // list id it contains the above 5000 usubcriber.
$content_subscriber_msg=array();
$testingmail="%%[ Var @text
Set @text = abcidId
]%% 
";
$files=shell_exec("ls *******/*.html");  //location of html file.
$fileNames=explode("\n",$files);
for($i=0;$i<count($fileNames)-1;$i++)
{
    $filename=basename($fileNames[$i]);
    if($filename!=""){
        $file_userid_array=explode('.',$filename);
        $userid =$file_userid_array[0];
        if(is_numeric($userid)){
            $homepage = file_get_contents($fileNames[$i]);      
            $testingmail=$testingmail."%%[if @text =='$userid' then]%% $homepage %%[endif]%% ";
        }
    }
}

$email = new ET_Email();
$email->authStub = $myclient;
$emailBody = <<<EMAIL
$testingmail
EMAIL;
$customer_key=uniqid('newsletter_');
$email->props = array("CustomerKey" => "$customer_key", "Name"=>"Weekly_Newsletter", "Subject"=>"Your Events",  "HTMLBody"=> $emailBody,  "EmailType" => "HTML", "IsHTMLPaste" => "true","CharacterSet"=>"UTF-8");
$response = $email->post();
$emailID = $response->results[0]->NewID;

$send = array();
$send["Email"] = array("ID"=> $emailID);
$send["List"] = array("ID"=> "$newListID");
$response = new ET_Post($myclient, "Send", $send);
```

Please let me know where I mistake.

Comment: Can you log the SOAP call being made to ExactTarget? Are you still getting the `out of memory` error?

Comment: Should I run the code for above 5000 users? Also I have  added the $doc->loadXML($request,LIBXML_PARSEHUGE) in ET_Client.php. Where is my SOAP log?.

Comment: Your logs will be on your server somewhere - you would need to configure those accordingly.  Then use the following `ET_Client(false,true)` to create your client. I would suggest starting with a smaller subset to see what you are getting.

Comment: Have you been able to get anything working yet?